# Java JDA Discord app - Can't add reaction to received messages

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to add a custom emote to messages that contain certain words. I've tried using the addReaction(Emote) and addReaction(String) methods in every way I can find. I just can't get the bot to add reactions to a message (its also not working with unicode emojis).

I've used the following methods below

```
event.getMessage().addReaction("name:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
event.getMessage().addReaction("name");
event.getMessage().addReaction("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
event.getMessage().addReaction(Emote emote);
```

It just seems to not work any way. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

The bot does a lot of other functions that all work fine. I do have a CS degree in Java so I have a good idea of how to write and structure code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDA uses [`RestActions`](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7)-Using-RestAction), they basically allow to queue all the actions into Discord and without them, your commands won't be sent to Discord. Your code doesn't work because you've forgotten to include the RestAction.

As to your attempts to add a reaction, read the [relevant JDA Docs](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#addReaction(net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Emote%29) to get an idea of what you should type in the parameters.

In short, you can either use the [`Emote`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Emote.html) instance or an [emote Unicode](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#addReaction(java.lang.String%29). There are a few ways to retrieve an emote's Unicode, for instance, [Emoji Unicode Table](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode).

You can also use the bot located at the official [JDA Discord Server](https://discord.gg/0hMr4ce0tIk3pSjp) by sending the next message:
`%emote EMOJI` (replace `EMOJI` with an actual emoji) which will be replied with the Emote's unicode.

Note that the bot provides two different UTFs (`UTF32` and `UTF16`) while the table provides only `UTF32`, and it is more recommended to use `UTF16`. Example:
:smile: emote - `\u1F604 UTF32  [\uD83D\uDE04] UTF16`.

Then, simply paste the Unicode as a String as the parameter of `addReaction`. Make sure there is only one `\` and not two, since the IDE can automatically add an escape character in some cases. Examples to correct and incorrect usages:

CORRECT - `addReaction("\uD83D\uDE04").queue(); // reacts with :smile:`

INCORRECT - `addReaction("\\uD83D\\uDE04").queue(); // reacts with :smile:`

CORRECT - `addReaction("U+1F604").queue(); //reacts with :smile:`

CORRECT - `addReaction("\u1F604").queue(); // reacts with :smile:`

To use an `Emote`, use the `guild.getEmotesByName("name")` method on the guild where the emote is located. 
Note that this returns a list, you'll have to use the `.get` method to get the specific emote instance out of the list. Then you can use the `addReaction(Emote emote)` method.

Comment: ah Christ of course lol. I use them all day with sending messages its almost like a semi-colon you dont think about. Thank you!

Comment: could you show me an example of how to get an emote from the id? I'm still trying a lot of things and its returning null pointers as an emote or numberformatexceptions. I presume I'm getting the emote wrong

Comment: @JoeJJJ sure, I'll edit my answer to include an example of the correct use of `addReaction`.

Comment: Thanks. Im still really struggling with custom emotes still. any way you could show an example of that?

Comment: Sure, for custom emotes, this is the format: `<:name:guildID>`

Comment: @Edgar B. I kind of gave up on this in the end. I've currently got this and it doesn't work. I've tried a lot of things. Any way you could show me a proper example showing where to put quotation marks etc.?

    String emote = event.getJDA().getEmoteById(":EMOTE_NAME:GUILD_ID").getAsMention();
    event.getMessage().addReaction(emote).queue();

Comment: @JoeJJJ I the getEmoteById method is reserved to long values, which are the ID of an emote. If you want to get an Emote from a different guild, use the Guild#getEmotesByName, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Your 4th example is incorrect since `"\u1F604"` is `"\u1F60" + "4"`. Java strings use UTF-16 escapes rather than full codepoints.

Comment: @Minn Thank you for your feedback! So the last example would be correct without that 4 at the end, correct?

Comment: That would be a valid codepoint but probably not what you want since that wouldn't be a valid emoji